# MpMovieController maximize and minimize button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

If you use

```
   controller.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

there is a button in controlBar to enterFullScreen with a callback with  **MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification** and when Done button is pressed you get a callback of **MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification** .How can I have one button in the controlbar that makes the moviePlayer enterFullscreen and when the user taps its again the movieplayer exitsFromFullScreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my answer, I subclassed **MPMoviePlayerViewController** added a button to it for minimizing it, then I added movieplayer as **containerViewController**(so that I can animate it to small screen). Animation was added to always keep the MPMoviePlayerViewController at the bottom left. Then I added **tap gesture** to  minmized screen view so that when a user taps the minimized screen it should turn back to maximized mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your problem, you can just add a button in a view in front of the MVMC (by subviewing the MVMC `view`) and make this button change the `fullscreen` property of the MVMC.